# imacros/Javascript if else exists Text

Tags: javascript, if-statement, imacros, exists

I'm using iMacros v9.0.3 on Firefox 53.0.3 (64 bit) in Windows 8 x64

I'm attempting imacros to check the text exists - if it exists then run the rest of the script, otherwise go to the particular URL

**Here is the block of my code:**

```
var n1 = prompt("Enter Number Of Clicks You Want: ");
    iimPlay('CODE:'+'SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 100'+'\nURL GOTO=http://addmefast.com/welcome');
    iimPlay('CODE:'+'wait seconds=1');
    iimPlay('CODE:'+'SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 100'+'\nURL GOTO=http://addmefast.com/free_points/instagram_likes');

    for(var P = 1; P <= n1; P++)
{
    iimDisplay("Current Click is: "+P)
    iimPlay('CODE:'+'SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0'+'\nTAG POS=1 TYPE=h2 ATTR=class:center_title&&TXT:Instagram<sp>Likes CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER');
    iimPlay('CODE:'+'wait seconds=2');
    iimPlay('CODE:'+'SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0'+'\nTAG POS=1 TYPE=div ATTR=class:btn3&&TXT:Like');
    iimPlay('CODE:'+'SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 20'+'\nTAG POS=1 TYPE=a ATTR=class:_1b8in<sp>_soakw<sp>coreSpriteDesktopNavLogoAndWordmark&&href:/&&TXT:Instagram CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER');
    iimPlay('CODE:'+'wait seconds=6');
    iimPlay('CODE:'+'SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0'+'\nTAG POS=1 TYPE=span ATTR=class:_soakw<sp>coreSpriteHeartOpen&&TXT:Like');
    iimPlay('CODE:'+'wait seconds=9');
    iimPlay('CODE:'+'\nEVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR=* CHAR="1" MODIFIERS="ctrl"');
    iimPlay('CODE:'+'TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS');
    iimPlay('CODE:'+'wait seconds=5');
    if (P % 5 == 0 && P!=0) {
iimPlay('CODE:'+'REFRESH');
}
}
```

My code is working fine but unfortunately, sometimes Tab 2 closed instead of Tab 1, so the script ends up with fails and need a manual work to replay again, so i want the script in If Else format

I don't have a great knowledge in javascript/programming. I searched Google and tried some of the suggestions but none have worked.

**Here is the code that I'm trying:**

```
 var n1 = prompt("Enter Number Of Clicks You Want: ");
    var answer=iimGetLastExtract();
        iimPlay('CODE:'+'SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 100'+'\nURL GOTO=http://addmefast.com/welcome');
        iimPlay('CODE:'+'wait seconds=1');
        iimPlay('CODE:'+'SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 100'+'\nURL GOTO=http://addmefast.com/free_points/instagram_likes');

        for(var P = 1; P <= n1; P++)
    {
        iimDisplay("Current Click is: "+P)
        iimPlay('CODE:'+'SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0'+'\nTAG POS=1 TYPE=h2 ATTR=class:center_title&&TXT:Instagram<sp>Likes EXTRACT=TXT');

if(answer=="Instagram Likes"){
        iimPlay('CODE:'+'wait seconds=2');
        iimPlay('CODE:'+'SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0'+'\nTAG POS=1 TYPE=div ATTR=class:btn3&&TXT:Like');
        iimPlay('CODE:'+'SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 20'+'\nTAG POS=1 TYPE=a ATTR=class:_1b8in<sp>_soakw<sp>coreSpriteDesktopNavLogoAndWordmark&&href:/&&TXT:Instagram CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER');
        iimPlay('CODE:'+'wait seconds=6');
        iimPlay('CODE:'+'SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0'+'\nTAG POS=1 TYPE=span ATTR=class:_soakw<sp>coreSpriteHeartOpen&&TXT:Like');
        iimPlay('CODE:'+'wait seconds=9');
        iimPlay('CODE:'+'\nEVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR=* CHAR="1" MODIFIERS="ctrl"');
        iimPlay('CODE:'+'TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS');
        iimPlay('CODE:'+'wait seconds=5');
        if (P % 5 == 0 && P!=0) {
    iimPlay('CODE:'+'REFRESH');
    }
} else {iimPlay('CODE:'+'SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 100'+'\nURL GOTO=http://addmefast.com/free_points/instagram_likes');}
    }
```

So, whats wrong in this code, and how can I fix it?

Comment: @eouw0o83hf thank you mate for fix my pathetic English :)

Comment: Glad to help out, sorry I can't actually answer the question!